# android:fitsSystemWindows="true" only works for one view

Tags: java, android

I create a project and there is only one activity. of course there is only a xml file.

There are two `ImageView` in xml file, one is in the top and another is at the bottom. I set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` for every ImageView so that the top ImageView will show below status bar and the bottom ImageView can show up navigation bar.

But `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` only works for the bottom ImageView.

Can anyone please tell me how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Give `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the root element of the layout

Comment: I understand this idea, but I want to know why there is only one works?